# CentOS 7 minimal install can't detect ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet, centos-7

I recently installed CentOS 7 on my desktop computer and decided on the minimal install.  It couldn't find a network device in the installation process, but I went ahead and installed it anyway. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 didn't exist to start. ifcfg-lo was the only one:

```
[chris@piecework4 /]$ ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts | grep ifcfg-
ifcfg-lo
```

I made ifcfg-eth0 with the following values:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="eth0"
HWADDR=00:13:D4:37:42:39
```

ifconfig -a only shows this:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8  bytes 560 (560.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8  bytes 560 (560.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I do have an Ethernet controller...

```
[chris@piecework4 /]$ lspci | grep Ethernet
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet (rev 90)
```

Ethernet works fine on every live cd I try.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with VMWare try following:

I added the following line to my .vmx file:

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
```

reference: [www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47724](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47724)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working a CentOS installation VM and want to have internet access with Oracle Virtualbox Click > Settings > Network > (Attached to:) Bridged Adapter.

Comment: (1) Please give clearer instructions.   (2) Politeness is great, but, if you’re contributing an answer, why are you saying “Thanks”?

Answer (score -1):

Just use Centos_64 as OS instead of CentOS and this will add (`ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"`) line to your configuration file

[image]

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: well , i added ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000" line but it did not worked , i had to use CentOS_64 as version to get it work ,